# Universal dg-algebra of an $A_\infty$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-categories, operads

In [this document](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/ainffun.pdf#page=4) by Keller, proposition 2.1, it is stated that for every $A_\infty$-algebra $A$ there is a universal dg-algebra $U(A)$ w.r.t. the existence of an $A_\infty$-morphism $A\to U(A)$, and this universal morphism is a quasi-isomorphism.

Now, what is $U(A)$? My first thought (I haven't understood rectification properly yet) would have been to quotient out the images of all higher structure maps $m_n$, $n> 2$ of $A$, but I am not sure if that gives any meaningful object.

Is there a hands-on description of the dg-algebra Keller mentions?

Answer (score 1):

As Keller says, "cf. Section 4.8". In Section 4.8, he says "Let us put $U(A) = \Omega B_\infty A$." Here $\Omega$ is the cobar construction (bottom of page 12), and $B_\infty$ is an $A_\infty$-version of the bar construction (defined about line 10 of page 14).

Comment: Well… I had hoped that there is something slightly more accessible :(.

Comment: The bar construction is a tensor coalgebra, and the cobar construction is a tensor algebra, so in that sense it is very explicit. The differentials incorporate the $A_\infty$-structure, so they have to be complicated.

Comment: I have read §4 until §4.8. I guess I now have an idea of what the symbols mean, but I think a spelled-out elementary example (really elementary) would be extremely useful for me. Do you know if such an example can be found somewhere?

Comment: I don't know of one, but start with $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ with the obvious multiplication and trivial $m_i$ for $i \neq 2$. Then $B_\infty A = BA$ should just be the dual of a polynomial algebra (as a coalgebra), trivial differential. $\Omega B A$ will unfortunately be large.